# Swift : How can we close Biometric Authentication programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, biometrics

I'm using `biometric auth` to authenticate myself in my personal app.
So far if I want to cancel or close the biometric auth popup, I should press on cancel to do so.

Code

```
let reason = "Log in to your account"
context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in

    if success {

        // Move to the main thread because a state update triggers UI changes.
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.state = .loggedin
        }

    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")

        // Fall back to a asking for username and password.
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to do this programmatically. Say I'm going to close it after 30 seconds.

**Is there a way to close Biometric Auth programmatically in Swift?**

Comment: Hint: How do you stop `Timer`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514192-invalidate

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much. You are very helpful